# How to Use UUID as Foreign Key in Postgresql with hibernate

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to persist a Person with a Set of Emails using JPA, but I couldn get there.

I'm getting this exception -

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "person" does not exist

I have a "Person" and a Set of "Email" for that Person. What am I doing wrong?

My code is below

creting table

```
CREATE TABLE "Person" (
  publicId uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (publicId)
);

CREATE TABLE "Email" (
  emailId uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emailId),
  FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES Person (publicId)
);
```

Entities

Person

```
@Id
@Column(name = "publicId")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID publicId;

@NotBlank
@Column
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
private Set<Email> emails;
```

Email

```
@Id
@Column(name = "emailId")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID emailId;

@NotBlank
@Column
private String email;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="publicId", nullable=false)
private Person person;
```

and my DTOs

DtoPersonCreate

```
@NotBlank
@VerifiedName
private String name;


@NotEmpty(message = "Input email list cannot be empty.")
private Set<DtoEmail> emails;
```

DtoEmail

```
@NotBlank
private String email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Email table has a couple issues. First it doe not contain a column for to identify the related row in the Person table. Second since your tables are created with double quotes (") **every reference** to it must also be in double quotes. As your referenced table is not double quoted it does not exist. I.E the table Person is not the same as table "Person".
Solution: Add the column publicId and double quote the referenced table. (even better would to get rid of double quotes if you can.)

```
CREATE TABLE "Email" (
  emailId uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  publicId uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (emailId),
  FOREIGN KEY (publicId) REFERENCES "Person" (publicId)
);
```

Comment: I've tried chaging everything you told me to, but I still got an Exception
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "person" does not exist
  Posição: 13

Comment: You are still double quoting table names. Doing that makes the names case sensitive thus "public" and "Public" are not the same. Your entity list creates the former, your latest Email table references the later. **Tip** Avoid double quoting. There is very little gain for a great deal of headaches.